# Deployment failure of helloworld-spring-webapp, Spring 3 and Jersey sample to Glassfish 4

Tags: spring-3, glassfish-4, java-ee-7, jersey-2.0

I've pulled helloworld-spring-webapp from https://github.com/marko-asplund/jersey.git and tried to deploy it onto the latest Glassfish 4 application server, using java ee-7 (jdk 1.7.0_45) and jersey 2.3-SNAPSHOT.  Deployment fails with this error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Ref] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.UriRoutingContext(Ref, ProcessingProviders)]. Please see server.log for more details.

My installed version of Jersey on Glassfish 4 is 2.0-0.1, with an update available to move to 2.0-0.2.

I attempted this because I'm getting similar errors attempting to get CDI working with an application I'm working with, so it's fortunate to find that this example also fails with similar results.  Does anyone know how to make this deploy and function correctly with Glassfish 4?

Edit:

I pulled a mirror image of that example and pulled it again from the source (here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.4.1).  I can deploy that sample.  There is a reference to a jira item JERSEY-2032 in the latest pom of the helloworld-spring-webapp.  So now I need to figure out what was done differently between versions that makes this sample deploy correctly so that I can make the same changes to my work-in-progress application.